# Mysql trying to insert rows and ignore duplicate entries with lot of issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried many answers from what I have seen on this site including 'where not exists' clause. Here is the original sql I am dealing with

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Feed 
(FeedTypeID, CustomerID, Name, Code, Color, Icon, FeedTypeSortOrder, IsUsingEmailAddress, IsActive)
select DISTINCT
3, c.CustomerID, "Unattached Image", "Unattached Image", "0x0093D0", "offline_01.png", COALESCE((select MAX(FeedTypeSortOrder) as FeedTypeSortOrderMax     from tbl_Feed where FeedTypeID = 3 and customerid=c.CustomerID) + 1, 1), 0, 1 
from tbl_Customer c 
join tbl_Feed f on f.customerid = c.customerid 
where f.code != "Unattached Image"
```

If I run this twice, it enters another row for "Unattached Image". I want it to only join tables that don't already have this value... I thought for sure changing the where clause to `where not exist(select name from tbl_Feed where name != "Unattached Image")` but this updated 0 rows. Please advise.

Comment: what happens when you change quotes `"` to apostrophes `'`?

Comment: same issue, doesnt ignore rows that already exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use NOT EXISTS:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Feed 
(FeedTypeID, CustomerID, Name, Code, Color, Icon, FeedTypeSortOrder, IsUsingEmailAddress, IsActive)
select DISTINCT
3, c.CustomerID, 'Unattached Image', 'Unattached Image', '0x0093D0', 
'offline_01.png', COALESCE((select MAX(FeedTypeSortOrder) as FeedTypeSortOrderMax     from tbl_Feed where FeedTypeID = 3 and customerid=c.CustomerID) + 1, 1), 0, 1 
from tbl_Customer c 
join tbl_Feed f on f.customerid = c.customerid 
where NOT EXISTS(select 1 from tbl_Feed where name = 'Unattached Image' AND CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
```